# Bootstrap page centering not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to create a page layout but the content is always slightly to the left more than the right. I notice that the row class has a margin left of -20px which I believe is the cause of the problem, but surely that can't be right?

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="row header-wrap">
    <div class="container header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
            test
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
            test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

BTW Header and header-wrap are not defined yet.

The purpose of the outer row div is to create a continual background for the header later.

---

[image]

Comment: Actually, by default the bootstrap page layout is centred. What do you want to be centred? The text or the layout?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar The layout, as you can see in my edit, it is not centered.

Comment: Remove the Row above the container class see what happens. Do you really need a row and then a container?

Comment: Dude, this is called centered. You want the text test to be centered?

Comment: Yes, as that gives me the ability to add a background that stretches across the screen on all resolutions. If I remove it, the layout is slightly to the right instead of the left.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Please look carefully at the left and right hand-sides of the red.

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) on this? So that we can test it live. I feel this might be because of the scrollbars. Correct me if I am wrong. By the way, what browser?

Comment: Let me just recreate that, will get back with you in a sec.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar I am using Chrome. I just tested by adding overflow-y:scroll and it still has the offset :( http://jsfiddle.net/VCfP9/

Comment: Done... :) Got the issue.

Comment: Like I said just remove the row class above the container or rename it other than "row" it will solve it for you. I have recreated it and looks centered here.

Comment: @imperium2335 if you could explain what are you trying to achieve with the row above the container in DEEP, I could help much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why using the row div without a parent div,is a bad idea ?

It will never let you center the content , reason the row class has a negative margin of -20px to the left , that being said any styling applied with the row will always flow out on the left hand side and hence not centering the elements inside it. So using a div around it as a parent, solves the problem. The way you are using row class is a wrong way to use it .

You can implement your design in the following way :
Jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/aBBsU/show)

```
<header>
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
        test
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
        test
          </div>

    </div>
   </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got your issue. You are using `.row` twice. Remove the `.row` from here:

```
<div class="row header-wrap">
```

And make it to:

```
<div class="header-wrap">
```

Also, give the background colour to the `.header-wrap` instead of `.container`.

#### See the output at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/VCfP9/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: @Preveen Jumar That is effectively the same as Akash Soti answer, which means I can't have a continual background for the header.

Comment: Wait... Continual background for header, you mean full width?

Comment: @imperium2335 Updated the answer. Check.

Comment: Yes, full width. Swapping the backgrounds doesn't change anything, the row is still not centered :(